# Android Syntax during tutorial

Tags: java, android

I've just started doing Android programming and I know some Java. But some of the code seems really weird to me. For example

```
Thread timer = new Thread()
{
    public void run() {
        try {
           sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Intent openStartingPoint= new Intent("com.example.myfirstapp.MAINACTIVITY"); 
            startActivity(openStartingPoint);
        }
    }
};
```

I'm not too sure what's going on I make a new instance of thread but why am I allowed to do brackets right after

Comment: It would be better if you could refer both java documentation and developer.android.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an anonymous class implementation of thread, read more about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: thanks that makes a lot more sense now!